# Сканирование портов средствами nmap с последующим добавлением результата в один csv файл

Tags: bash, csv, ip, port

Есть файл servers.csv с списком ip адресов, я запускаю команду:
`nmap -sT -iL servers.csv  >> $HOME/outputs.csv`

И получаю вывод в таком формате:

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-05 09:07 MSK
Nmap scan report for 10.200.230.167
Host is up (0.0019s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
8443/tcp open  https-alt
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 15.70 seconds
```

Моя цель — объединить эти два файла **servers.csv** и **outputs.csv** в первой строке ip адреса, а во второй порты, вот пример как я это вижу:

| IP | PORT |
| --- | --- |
| 10.200.230.167 | 53,80,4438,443 |

Comment: *Моя цель объединить эти два файла servers.csv и outputs.csv в первом столбце айпи адреса а в втором столбце порты,вот пример как я это вижу: 
IP                               PORT
10.200.230.167         53,80,4438,443

Comment: Вероятно вопрос в том как это сделать? Создать цикл по IP из вашего файла с адресами, делать nmap и grep'ать 'open' понадобится постобработка(например awk) чтобы открытые порты выводить как CSV. Затем вывод готовой строки, например так: `printf '%-20s%-20s' $ip $ports`.

Comment: @Ivan можно и через `sed`: `| grep open | sed 's#/.*##g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g' && echo " "`

Comment: @DiMithras ИМХО awk более универсален, собственно тут можно вот так сделать на самом деле: `nmap -sT -iL servers.csv | awk '{...}'` т.к. nmap может со списком работать.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, команда должна выглядеть так ?
nmap -sT -iL servers.csv  >> $HOME/outputs.csv  |  awk -F, '{print $1, $NF}' output.csv | cut -d',' -f1,2,5,7 > outputport.csv

Comment: @user559676 нет, вот так: `nmap -sT -iL servers.csv | awk '{...}' > outputport.csv` и вля логика тут внутри awk'а получается.

Comment: @Ivan да я не спорю, что awk крут, просто как вариант написал :)

Comment: @DiMithras Разнообразие вариантов это хорошо.

Comment: @Ivan к слову, попробовал погонять на WSL, у меня `nmap localhost | grep 'report\|open' | sed 's#.*(\|/.*##g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'` выдаёт всё хорошо, но не выдаёт ip, очень странно. Тут стоит отметить, что nmap версии 7.94, там ip в скобках `()`. Если есть красивое решение с `awk`, было бы интересно увидеть в ответе.

Comment: Попробовал вашу команду, в целом очень близко к тому что я хочу, вот такой результат получился:
    Nmap scan report for 10.201.270.112,53,80,443,8443,10.176.15.7),80,Nmap scan report for 10.156.26.82,80,10.146.40.91),80,443,10.136.66.88),80,443

Comment: Оформил в ответ, дополнил пайпами, попробуйте всю команду целиком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По комментариям:
Что же, это замечательно, что мой вариант отработал, потому что у меня:

```bash
nmap localhost | grep 'report\|open' | sed 's#.*(\|/.*##g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
```

###### Выдаёт:

```
,25,135,445,1001,24800
```

То есть ip адрес куда-то обрезается, с чем это связано, я так и не понял. Возможно как-то связано с тем, что я запускаю команды под WSL.
Но‥ раз у вас отработало, предлагаю и дальше работать с тем что получилось.

### Решение

Изначально хотел использовать круглые скобки, по ним можно легко найти начало и конец ip адреса, но у вас выходит, что где-то скобки есть, где-то их нет. Абстрагируемся от скобок, изменим `sed 's#.*(\|/.*##g'` на `s#.*for \|/.*##g`, подойдёт для случаев, если у вас только ip адреса, а не хосты, и дополним постобработку так, чтобы было похоже на csv:

```bash
nmap -sT -iL servers.csv | grep 'report\|open' | sed 's#.*for \|/.*##g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' | sed 's/(\|)//g' | sed 's/\(\.[[:digit:]]*\),/\1\t/g' | sed 's/,\([[:digit:]]*\.\)/\n\1/g'
```

###### Вывод:

```
10.156.26.82    80
10.146.40.91    80,443
10.136.66.88    80,443
```

По пайпам пошагово:

1. `grep 'report\|open'`
   Выбираем строки где содержится ip адрес и открытые порты
2. `sed 's#.*for \|/.*##g'`
   Убираем весь текст до ip адреса и после портов (`/` и далее)
3. `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'`
   Убираем все переносы строки, при этом последний останется, не надо в конце делать `&& echo " "`, что удобно, подробнее про решение [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/8489602) на английском SO, перевод объяснения оттуда:

   0. `sed` начинается с чтения первой строки, исключая новую строку, в пространство шаблона.
   1. Создаётся метка через `:a`.
   2. Добавляется новая строка и следующая строка в пространство шаблона через `N`.
   3. Если мы находимся перед последней строкой, делаем ветку на созданную метку `$!ba` (`$!` означает не делать этого на последней строке. Это необходимо для того, чтобы избежать повторного выполнения `N`, что приведет к завершению скрипта, если больше не будет ввода!).
   4. Наконец, подстановка заменяет каждую новую строку запятой на пространстве шаблона (которым является весь поток).
4. `sed 's/(\|)//g'`
   Убираем `(` и `)`, в принципе, этот шаг можно объединить с пунктом 2: `sed 's#.*for \|/.*\|(\|)##g'`, но оставлю как есть для читаемости.
5. Финальные штрихи, добавляем табуляцию и перенос где нужно:

   1. `sed 's/\(\.[[:digit:]]*\),/\1\t/g'`

      - Ищем точку (`\.`) после которой следуют числа и запятая, то есть конец ip адреса. Всё что до запятой берём в группу.
      - В замене используем группу `\1`, а запятую меняем на табуляцию `\t`
   2. `sed 's/,\([[:digit:]]*\.\)/\n\1/g'`

      - Здесь примерно то же самое, только запятую меняем перед ip адресом и не на табуляцию, а на перенос строки.

<sub>Получилась очень длинная команда, что не очень хорошо. Если есть более элегантное решение с `awk`, было бы приятно увидеть его в соседнем ответе.</sub>

Comment: добавил вариант с awk

Answer (score 1):

Спациально для @DiMithras вариант с awk:

```
nmap 192.168.0.1 127.0.0.1 | awk -F'[/ ]' '
    BEGIN{printf("%-20s%-20s\n", "IP", "PORTS")}
    /Nmap/{ip=$6; sep=""}
    /open/{ips[ip]=sprintf("%s%s%s", ips[ip], sep, $1); sep=","}
    END{for(ip in ips)printf "%-20s%-20s\n", ip, ips[ip]}
'
```

Результат:

```
IP                  PORTS               
(127.0.0.1)         22,631,1234,8080    
(192.168.0.1)       22,1234,8080
```

Моя версия nmap выводит ip в скобках оставил как есть для упрощения скрипта.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно симпатично вышло, надо будет изучить `awk`.